# Ensure that Groovy ArrayList objects are of the same class

Tags: java, arraylist, groovy

I have a Java class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int parentVal;
}
```

that will have several inherited Groovy classes like:

```
class Child1 extends Parent
{
    def value1;
}

class Child2 extends Parent
{
    def value2;
}
```

I would like to have a collection in Groovy that would be restricted to contain only Child1 or Child2 instances, so that if the collection contains Child1 instances it can't contain Child2 instances (or anything else). This my attempt at this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyCollection<T extends Parent>
{
    private ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

    public void setType(Class<T> cls)
    {
        this.cls = cls;
    }

    public void add(T item) throws Exception
    {
        if(item.getClass() == cls)
        {
            list.add(item);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("wrong argument type");
        }
    }

    public T getItem(int index)
    {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    private Class<T> cls;
}
```

and in my Groovy script:

```
def c1 = new Child1()
c1.value1 = 1
c1.parentVal = 2;

def c2 = new Child2()
c2.value2 = 2
c2.parentVal = 3;

def myCol = new MyCollection()
myCol.setType(Child1.class)

myCol.add(c1)
myCol.add(c2) // throws an exception
```

The last statement really throws the "wrong argument type" exception, but I'm new to Java and Groovy so I'm probably doing the whole thing wrong. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you did is throwing a runtime error. It isn't wrong, it just isn't checked at compile time. I'm not sure you could, using Java's generics, define an upper bound and a lower bound at the same declaration. By simply using `<T extends Parent>` it says you are up for anything which extends `Parent`, and that includes `Child2`, whilst you only wanted `Child1`. An alternative i can think is to define a generics on the Parent, and declaring it in the Child class with the class itself being the generic parameter. Then it throws a compiler error. Also note `@CompileStatic` or `@TypeChecked` are needed:

The `Parent` class with the generics declaration:

```
class Parent<T> {
    int parentVal
}

class Child1 extends Parent<Child1> {
    def value1;
}

class Child2 extends Parent<Child2> {
    def value2;
}

class MyCollection<T extends Parent<T>> {
    def list = new ArrayList<T>()

    void add(T item) throws Exception {
      list.add(item);
    }

    T getItem(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }
}
```

And the test script. Note the commented line doesn't compile:

```
//and in my Groovy script:
@groovy.transform.TypeChecked
def main() {
  def c1 = new Child1()
  c1.value1 = 1
  c1.parentVal = 2;

  def c2 = new Child2()
  c2.value2 = 2
  c2.parentVal = 3;

  def myCol = new MyCollection<Child1>()

  myCol.add(c1)
  //myCol.add(c2) // doesn't compile
}


main()
```

Comment: Thank you both for the answers

Answer (score 1):

Since groovy supports generics

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Generics

You could probably do with declaring an `ArrayList<Child1>` and groovy would solve the problem for you.

Comment: It appears that event if I declare and ArrayList<Child1> in groovy it accepts Child2 instances or event integers

Comment: Try with `@CompileStatic` or `@TypeChecked`